# An Unexpected Server error has occurred in JDeveloper

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I use Oracle Weblogic server and JDeveloper 12c (install oracle fusion soa suite including jDeveloper) to create some Web SERVICE need it in my project.
jDeveloper worked for some days , but now when I tried to test simple web service "hello world" it return a "popup"

```
*An Unexpected Server error has occurred in JDeveloper*
```

and this is a message returned in the console

```
  Nov 11, 2015 11:36:06 AM oracle.bali.xml.addin.XMLSourceNode getXmlContext
SEVERE: Error creating XmlContext for oracle.ide.Context[{Context.EVENT=java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(195,196),absolute(247,326),button=3,modifiers=Meta+Button3,extModifiers=Button3,clickCount=1] on nav-AppServerNavigatorManager, Context.VIEW=ApplicationServerNavigatorViewType.ApplicationServerNavigatorName, ExplorerContext.TNODES=[Loracle.ide.explorer.TNode;@1893566a, NavigatorWindow=ApplicationServerNavigatorViewType.ApplicationServerNavigatorName, Context.SELECTION=[Loracle.ide.model.Element;@710e55c0, Context.WORKSPACE=HelloWorld.jws, Context.NODE=bpelprocess1_client_ep (ws), Context.PROJECT=ProjectHelloWorld.jpr}]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: XmlContext:  Error acquiring text buffer for file: https://iteslab-OptiPlex-7020:7102/soa-infra/services/default/ProjectHelloWorld!1.0/bpelprocess1_client_ep?WSDL
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.XMLSourceNode._getXmlContext(XMLSourceNode.java:1695)
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.XMLSourceNode.getXmlContext(XMLSourceNode.java:192)
    at oracle.bali.xml.gui.jdev.JDevXmlContext.getXmlContext(JDevXmlContext.java:224)
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.CheckSyntaxController._getDocumentElement(CheckSyntaxController.java:637)
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.CheckSyntaxController.update(CheckSyntaxController.java:276)
    at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction$ControllerDelegatingController.update(IdeAction.java:1487)
    at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.updateAction(IdeAction.java:783)
    at oracle.ide.controller.MenuManager.updateMenuItemAction(MenuManager.java:1257)
    at oracle.ide.controller.MenuManager.updatePopupMenuItems(MenuManager.java:1228)
    at oracle.ide.controller.ContextMenu.prepareShow(ContextMenu.java:329)
    at oracle.ide.controller.ContextMenu.show(ContextMenu.java:290)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.tryPopup(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2302)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.BaseTreeExplorer.mousePressed(BaseTreeExplorer.java:2234)
    at oracle.ideimpl.explorer.CustomTree.processMouseEvent(CustomTree.java:232)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at oracle.ide.net.HttpURLFileSystemHelper.openInputStream(HttpURLFileSystemHelper.java:476)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.openInputStream(URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:291)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.openInputStream(URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:291)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.ide.InterruptableHttpURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.openInputStream(InterruptableHttpURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:134)
    at oracle.ideimpl.net.LazyURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.openInputStream(LazyURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:364)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystem.openInputStream(URLFileSystem.java:1368)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystemHelper.createReader(URLFileSystemHelper.java:1536)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.createReader(URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:343)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.createReader(URLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:343)
    at oracle.ideimpl.net.LazyURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.createReader(LazyURLFileSystemHelperDecorator.java:426)
    at oracle.ide.net.URLFileSystem.createReader(URLFileSystem.java:1707)
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.XMLSourceNode.createReader(XMLSourceNode.java:1304)
    at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.loadTextBuffer(TextNode.java:302)
    at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.openImpl(TextNode.java:537)
    at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:1045)
    at oracle.ide.model.Node.open(Node.java:992)
    at oracle.ide.model.TextNode.acquireTextBufferOrThrow(TextNode.java:812)
    at oracle.bali.xml.addin.XMLSourceNode._getXmlContext(XMLSourceNode.java:1687)
    ... 44 more
```

how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: What happens if you go to the URL it's reporting (https://iteslab-OptiPlex-7020:7102/...) in your browser, or from the command line with curl/wget? Does it exist? Is whatever is providing that service running? (I think you'd get a different error, but does it have a self-signed certificate?)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your interest.
I tried with [http://192.168.1.76:7102/....] but the browser displayed this :
" �P " instead of the WSDL file.